# Is srcset required for displaying HQ retina images?

Tags: html, responsive-images, srcset

Let's say that I have an image `600x300px`.

I display it with this code:

```
<img src="image600x300.jpg" style="width: 300px;" />
```

The actual size of the displayed image will be `300x150px`.

A smart browser could use two pixels to render each pixel (i.e. retina image). But... they do it automatically?

**Do you get an improved result in the quality of the rendered image if you add `srcset` with the exact same image?**

```
<img src="image600x300.jpg" srcset="image600x300.jpg 2x" style="width: 300px;" />
```

Comment: I would imagine as a default reference to *retina* this is covered by the `<viewport ` declaration in the `<head>` of your HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

No. You are providing the same image in both cases. The `2x` is a descriptor meant to help the browser decide on which image to use.

In this case, you are saying "if the device supports 2x pixel density, use this image instead" (but you provide the same image as the default).